# Create event on Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to create an event using graph API with following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"venue name",@"name",
                                   @"2012-01-13T17:00:00+0000",@"start_time",
                                   @"2012-01-16T01:30:00+0000",@"end_time",@"location",@"location name ch",@"1234567890",@"id", nil];
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/events"
                          andParams:params  
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                        andDelegate:self];
```

but when I am trying to create the event, an alert comes with "Facebook Fail bad URL". Can any one suggest what I am doing wrong or what I am missing in parameters or anywhere or is there any other method?

-Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because there is no param id.

If you want to set venue location, use location_id.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing the same thing with the same parameters here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and see what the error message is.